# how to figure out what class called a method in java?

Tags: java, class

How do I figure out what class called my method without passing any variable to that method?
let's say we have something like this:

```
Class A{}
Class B{}
Class C{
public void method1{}
System.out.print("Class A or B called me");
}
```

let's say an instance of Class A calls an instance of class C and the same for class B. When class A calls class C method1 method, I want it to print something like "Class A called me", and when class B called it to print "Class B called me".

Comment: Why do you want to know what class called your method? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Quoi Why should it be static? Is that because it is accessing StackTrace and we want only one instance to have access to that?

Comment: @SteveKuo I don't have a real application in mind, it came up once we were having a java debate with some colleagues

Comment: I know this question is really old but one reason this might be useful is something I am currently running into: I have a method that is being called 10 times and it should only be called once. Figuring out what is calling the method helps to navigate the stack and locate the bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no really easy way to do this, because normally a method doesn't and shouldn't need to care from where it is called. If you write your method so that it behaves differently depending on where it was called from, then your program is quickly going to turn into an incomprehensible mess.

However, here's an example:

```
public class Prut {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example();
    }

    public static void example() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement element = stackTrace[2];
        System.out.println("I was called by a method named: " + element.getMethodName());
        System.out.println("That method is in class: " + element.getClassName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I do assume that this is the structure of the stacktrace 'String declaringClass,
                         String methodName,
                         String fileName,
                         int lineNumbe' as you used the second one, or should it be the stackTrace[1]?

Comment: @sheidaei Yes, lookup the API documentation of class `StackTraceElement`.

Comment: @sheidaei No it should be `stackTrace[2]` - try it out.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`

It returns an array of `[StackTraceElements][1]` which represents the current stack trace of a program.

Comment: +1 Doing this is very expensive. It should be avoid if performance is important. e.g. Logging often uses this and it can slow down your application significantly.

Comment: Note that this is likely to be quite a slow operation, so think carefully before using it.  Also it doesn't help if there are intervening stack frames between you and your "real" caller, for example if the call was via reflection.

Comment: Yes and it also throws SecurityException if a security manager doesn't allow getting the stack trace of thread.

Comment: @Quoi when you are talking about security manager, you are talking about a J2EE framework?

Comment: you can set custom security policy in System by  System.setSecurityManager(SecurityManager);