# How to protect instantiation of concrete subclasses when using factory pattern?

Tags: java, factory-pattern

I have an abstract class `Employee` with two concrete subclasses, `MinorEmployee` and `AdultEmployee`. I know how to create a static factory method in `Employee` that instantiates an instance of a concrete subclass:

```
public abstract class Employee() {
    public static Employee create(LocalTime birthdate) {
        if (/* omitted */) {
            return new MinorEmployee();
        } else {
            return new AdultEmployee();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way in Java to prevent a caller in the same package from directly instantiating a `MinorEmployee` or `AdultEmployee`?

I can't make their constructors private, or `Employee` wouldn't be able to access them. I also don't want to nest them inside of `Employee`.

Comment: Maybe if you made `MinorEmployee` and `AdultEmployee` private static members of `Employee`... But if it makes sense for `Employee` to access those constructors (based on scope), then it should be reasonable to consider other classes of the same package as in the right scope to do it too...

Comment: factory classes should ideally be separate from the Entity classes, IMO.

Comment: Thank you, @ernest_k. I should have stated in the question that I don't want to use nested classes as well as inner classes. I have updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you hint on something you can try, though there can be some caveats:

- create a separate factory class instead of base class.
- make the constructor private in the the factory class
- instantiate a dummy private object in the factory class
- Let `MinorEmployee` and `AdultEmployee` 's only constructor accept object of factory class. Since object of factory can not exist out side the class due to private constructor, practically no one else should be able to instantiate those classes from outside.
- Use the dummy object to pass on in your factory method.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the constructors in `MinorEmployee` and `AdultEmployee` as `private` and then use reflection in your factory method:

```
public static Employee create(LocalTime birthdate) {
    try {
        Class<? extends Employee> clazz;
        if (omitted) {
            clazz = MinorEmployee.class;
        } else {
            clazz = AdultEmployee.class;
        }
        Constructor<? extends Employee> cons = clazz.getConstructor();
        cons.setAccessible(true);
        return cons.newInstance();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
            | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        // handle the exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

You can make the constructors private and use an auxiliary method to identify from where the request of new entity is coming. If is coming from where you want, return a new instance of the object else, you can throw and an exception.

[how to figure out what class called a method in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161158/how-to-figure-out-what-class-called-a-method-in-java)